# Add Mocha tests to Quasar and Vue.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js

I recently moved from Vue.js to Quasar (*which is just a set of components for Vue.js applications*)

I have two different applications, one written using `vue-cli` and one with `quasar-cli`.
The one with `vue-cli` has all test structure in place, I can just execute `npm run unit` and it finds all my mocha tests and run them.

I have then copied the same structure into my quasar project. It builds and run in `dev` mode correctly but when I execute this command:

```
cross-env BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js --single-run
```

I get these errors:

- Typescript emitted no output for ..\src\sfc.d.ts
- Module parse failed: ..\src\index.html Unexpected token (1:0)
  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'quasar/dist/quasar.start.css' in '..\src'

Somehow I am missing some configuration which is needed before I start karma. Any clue? In Vue.js using Typescript the same configuration is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you haven't changed the karma.conf.js.
If that is the case, you need to install html-loader to be able to load html files during test. Next, for css you will need to include the styleRules utility from `build/css-utils.js`.

In webpack.test.conf.js:

```
module: {
    rules: cssUtils
        .styleRules({
            sourceMap: true,
            postcss: true,
        })
        .concat([{
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader',
        }])
    ...
}
```

If that doesn't work, I might need to take a look at your changes in karma.conf.js and all related/required codes (e.g. webpack.test.conf.js, webpack.base.conf.js, test/unit/index.js, etc.)

EDIT:
This would not be the case anymore for Quasar v0.15+. You can go to the [guide](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/) to check out how you can use it for a Vue CLI project.